# Why doesn't this Django logging work?

Tags: django, logging

I'm having trouble getting going with Django logging.  I've read both the Python and Django documentation on logging but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong.  To start, I'm just trying to log a message to the console where my Django development server is running when I execute this simple view:

```
# demo/views.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def demo_logging(request, template):
    logger.error("Got some error")
    return render(request, template)
```

I'm using Django's default logging setting as specified in django/utils/log.py in my settings file so that I (hopefully) know exactly what's happening (which, clearly I don't):

```
# settings.py
DEBUG = True
...
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

When I execute the view, I don't see anything in the console except the message,

```
No handlers could be found for logger "demo.views"
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I would think calling logger.error would hit the django logger which is linked to the console handler which is defined.

Thanks.

**FOLLOW UP**
I solved this problem by adding a default, "catch-all" logger that would be triggered when creating a logger using the "__name__" argument:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Calling `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` causes the `logging` module to search for a logger named as your module (`demo.views`); as you have no logger defined by that name, it fails. To simply log to console, you can use the `django` logger defined in `'loggers'` key of your `LOGGING` configuration:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def demo_logging(request, template):
    logger.error("Got some error")
    return render(request, template)
```

Comment: This is true.  However, a better approach which I just discovered might be to add a default logger as shown above.  Given that the Django doc examples shows the use of "\_\_name\_\_" when specifying a logger, you'd think it would discuss creating a default, "catch-all" logger.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, makes one wonder why the docs don't mention that, or why isn't a 'catch-all' logger added by default.

Comment: So it simply fails. Without raising an exception.

Comment: @rafalmp I'm a bit late and also with a silly question, merely setting  up `django` logger  in settings.py stores all the logs from console into the file with a `file` handler, or it stores those only that we store from the views or relevant places.

Same settings work fine on local machine, but don't log all INFO level logs on production with APACHE.